# Adsense responsive ad not changing size

Tags: angularjs, adsense, angular-material

I have a page written in AngularJS and [Material Desing for AngularJS](https://material.angularjs.org). MD is a responsive user interface, and in this page I have placed a responsive ad unit.

The problem is that it seems that this responsive ad unit is not taking advantage of the responsiveness of Material Design and is always displaying ads in the smallest unit possible.

The ads are being displayed inside a `md-card` and I have a feeling that they are not able to correctly detect the element's width and height, and that's why it's displaying the smallest ad unit available always - on mobile or even on a desktop.

The page is live [here](http://tauc.link/the-premise-suspends-his-grave), you can check its source code.

Comment: just out of curiosity, don't you think that adsense will become worthless in the near future because of adbock? So is it realy worth it investing time in it?

Comment: It's a risk, but as at least hosting this site generate costs, unfortunately I have only two options: charge the users for the website services or delegate these costs to ads. I don't believe users would pay for a URL shortener, still, I don't want to pay those costs myself forever (as I currently am). I expect that this site can generate enough revenue from ads to at least maintain itself. That's why many thinks adblock is malicious for the Internet. Also, this site blocks adblock, give it a try ;)

Comment: send me the link. You could try a affiliate program, just my guess. still could you send me the link.

Comment: @Jayo2k Sorry, I realised the link I posted in the question was wrong. I edited the question, should be ok now. Anyway, I'm curious, really. Should I try a different way? Will ads die?

Comment: I do not really know but as adsense grow, I suspect ads might die, I am thinking about other way to make revenue. by the way, nice site. I find it interesting, never used angular before